# iOS Application Architecture for a Web Service App

Tags: ios, web-services, nsnotificationcenter

I am developing an application which is a client and is communicating with a web service. I am checking internet connection with [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class. If its avaliable, I set a bool as YES, its NO as default.

In my application delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, I grab a singleton object and add it for observing network status changes so it can turn bool into YES quickly.

When my first `viewDidLoad`, I try to `getToken` from web service so I check if `internetConnection` is avaliable and it always returns NO because my object gets a notification after I tried to get a token. I don't think its a good idea use a delayed performer, so how can I handle that situation. Thank in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case, i have used the `ASIHTTPRequest` library to check either the request was reaching the server or not. The ASIHTTPRequest offers a lot of methods including this one :

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

To test the connection, you can do something like this :

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{


if(request.responseStatusCode==200)
    {
          //successfull connection, do what you need
        }
else {
      //failed request sent, display the correspondant error

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your app name" 
                                                        message:@"Unexpected error" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }


}
```

Comment: Hmm thank you, it seems like this library is using Reachability too and do things that i try to.

Comment: @Haqn, Malloc, What design pattern should I use to separate classes, that will deal with services, from a business logic? Link to a diagram would be perfect.

Comment: @surlac, sorry surlac its going to be a late answer, I was away for a while. I used ASIHTTPRequest library and created a singleton to manage all connection stuff. If you use this library you do not need to think about separating classes for network stuff (of course it depends on your needs.) just create modal classes for your data and view them by your viewControllers! :)

Comment: @Haqn, thanks for the answer. I sticked to DAO pattern for CRUD. Also, ASIHTTPRequest is outdated, RestKit is nice for REST (atom,json), and sudzc with custom object mapper for SOAP.

Comment: Thank you for info, I will try them next time! :)